# Add before function in $.get ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here's my code:

```
$.get(site_url+'/core/includes/manipulate_player.php?action=delete&userid='+userid+'&productid='+productid, function(html){
        console.log(html);
//some other code here
    });
```

I want to add before function

```
beforeSend:function()
            {
            }
```

like in `$.ajax()`

Can anybody help me how to do that?

Comment: Why you didn't use `$.ajax()` ?

Comment: i know i can solve this with $.ajax(). But that's not my question. Let's suppose i used $.ajax() and solved the issue then also i want to know how it applies in $.get().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define function which call your beforeSend function and get request. Like that.

```
function getRequest(url, beforeSend) {
     beforeSend();

     $.get(url, function(response){
         console.log(response);
     });
}


getRequest('www.example.com?a=3', function() {
    console.log('function call before $.get send');
});
```